# Find instead of Filter Array in Swift

Tags: objective-c, arrays, search, swift

I have an array of PFObjects. I'd like to search if the "Type" contains "Sushi". The filter alters the array. How can I preform this search without altering the array?

```
func startCheckOptions(objects: [AnyObject]) {     
  let filteredArray = objects.filter() {
      if let type = ($0 as PFObject)["Type"] as String {
          //if "type" contains "sushi", then do something instead of alter array
          return type.rangeOfString("Sushi") != nil
      } else {
          return false
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the contains function:

```
func startCheckOptions(objects: [AnyObject]) -> Bool {     
    return contains(objects as [PFObject]) { (object) -> Bool in
        if let type = object["Type"] as? String {
            return type.rangeOfString("Sushi") != nil
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

if startCheckOptions(objects) {
    println("yes")
}
else {
    println("no")
}
```

This has the advantage of not building a new array containing the matching objects and stopping on the first match.

In this case you'd be better off protecting the objects cast (or really handling one time somewhere else) by casting it to `[PFObject]` ASAP.  Leaving `AnyObject` references floating around can only lead to confusion and heartache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention objects is type [AnyObject] (updated code). The code above generates the error at `contains`. "Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol Equatable"

Comment: thanks this code compiles without error. however, i don't quite understand how I can preform any action if "type" contains "sushi". For instance, I tried printing `yes` if true and `no` if false.

Comment: Maybe this edit answers your question, if it doesn't, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: yep, that's actually what I ended up doing, except all within the function (just added a second if statement for hasSushi). I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way because I will be checking multiple "Types"

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` does not alter an array, but it returns a new array. What you have above is correct. `objects` will be the original array, and `filteredArray` will be the new array consistent of objects where "type" is "sushi".

Comment: Is there a more direct way to check if the original array "Type" contains "Sushi" without requiring a return value.

Comment: You can use the contains() function.